# Create a board which shows a specific epic and all its tasks and subtasks in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

I am looking to create a board in JIRA that shows a specific epic and all the tasks and subtasks that come under that epic.

I have been modifying this JQL which shows all epics, tasks and subtasks for a project but am having problems filtering it so only the specific epic I am interested in shows.

```
(project = myProject AND issuetype = Epic AND "Epic Link" = myEpic) OR issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = myProject AND issuetype = Epic", "is epic of") OR issueFunction in subtasksOf("issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('project = myProject AND issuetype = Epic', 'is epic of')")
```

How can I can I get this to work or is there a better query or method?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you add "AND key = XXXX-xxx"  ?

Comment: Great.  That worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I posted my comment as answer in case you are kind to mark it as accepted answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add "AND key = XXXX-xxx" in your query.